# import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI not working

Tags: authentication, signing

ive being trying to write a loggin with google , phone and email activity, but the app is not  importing : com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI

this is my app build gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stockmng"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0'
    //apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    implementation 'com.github,MrNouri:DynamicSizes:1.0'
}
```

and my project gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories{
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i tried adding, changing updating the implentations in app build gradle,
i have permission.internet and ACCES_NETWORK_STATE added to the manifest.
a configured the api keys,and oAuth updated,
also adding in google maven and maven central in repository en the project gradel,
nothing works.